Looking for title of 70s or 80s French police film
I think the film was a French policier. It starts with a bank robbery. The visitors of the bank have to put brown paper bags over their heads. When the money doesn't come fast enough, the robbers shoot one of them. His blood splashes on the glass. I think the robbers then hide in some apartment. There is a girl. And I think they took some journalist as a hostage, who later decides voluntarily to stay with them, probably to be able to write an article about the whole story. In the end, there is a car chase and in two trucks block the street from both sides. Then the side of the truck falls away and police with machine guns on stands brutally execute the robbers (and the journalist) in their car. 

Welcome to Movies & TV stackexchange Please add any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), estimated year of release (or at least the year you saw it), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points. The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

Thanks for the welcome. I already wrote all the information I have above. I hope somebody will recognize the plot. I have searched extensively on the internet, including at some forums, so far without success.

Was it in color or B&W? And how sure are you about the language and year?

I think it was in color. I am pretty sure it was French, because I remember my father saying after the violent ending, that extreme violence is typical of French policiers. I must have seen it in the mid 80s, also because my father past away afterwards, and it looked a bit old, so my best guess is it is from somewhere in the 70s, but possibly a bit older even.

I think you're looking for Mesrine (Part 1&2) : Killer Instinct 
It was made in 2008 but it's about a famous french robber/assassin from the 1970s and is set at that time. Your description seems to match, especially the grand finale execution.
Hope I helped :)

Well then, why not Mesrine from 1984? ;) [Though I'm not sure it's either of these.]

Because 1- I haven't seen the 1984 movie (and didn't event know of its existence) and 2- the description of the scenes match the 2008 movie really well... but I'm guessing if I've got the right killer, Dovid will have no trouble finding which movie he/she's looking for ;)

Since I saw it in the 80s, it can not be the 2008 movie. I'll check the 1984 one, but I just had a look at the trailer, and did not recognize it. If it doesn't have precisely the elements I remember, it's not it. Will let you know soon.
